# Problem accessing imported modules with browser console

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, source-maps

When i try to log imported modules on browser console I get this error:
[image]

As you can see, `portal` has `app` and `default` but it breaks when logging because the modules have other name given by webpack. **My goal is log them with the original source name for debug purposes.** I think the problem is related with source maps configuration but i cant figure it out.

Below are the pseudo configuration files for explanation purposes:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es2017",
        "allowJs": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "paths": {
            "*": ["../../node_modules/@org/*", "../node_modules/@org/*"]
        },
        "baseUrl" : "./src",
        "outDir": "./dist"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src"
    ]
}
```

**webpack.config**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports={
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        library: {
            type: 'amd'
        },
        path: path.resolve( "dist"),
        chunkFormat: 'array-push'

    },
    target: "web",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js','.jsx','.json', '.tsx', '.scss']
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'dist', 'loaders'),
            path.resolve('node_modules')
        ]
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                use:  'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    externalsType: 'amd',
    entry: {
        index: './src/Index.ts',
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            module: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'module')
        }
    },
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "MyProject",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "./dist/index.js",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "dependencies": {
        "requirejs": "^2.3.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "webpack": "^5.75.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    }
}
```

Hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.